# Running perl scripts like php without CGI

Tags: perl, apache, module, cgi

Is it possible to run Perl script in web server without using CGI?
I mean, like php scripts (run any .pl file without `#!/path/to/interpreter` line).
If Yes, How?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't given quite enough context in your question; it's only from your comment below that it's absolutely clear you want to do this in a webserver context.  Which webserver are you using?

Comment: @itsbruce, as tags shows Apache

Comment: It is not safe to rely on tags with no other context; they may have been added by somebody else, who may have made an incorrect assumption

Comment: Belated, I know...but at that point you would see that the question was edited. I see no edit links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, with the `Action` directive:

```
AddHandler perl-files .pl
Action perl-files /path/to/perl/interpreter
```

Comment: I'm talking about the web server (apache) ! not terminal run.

Comment: @4r1y4n I guessed that, but you should have said that clearly in your question.

Comment: I said that ("web server")! and in question tags there are apache & module; anyway thanks

Comment: Should I load `mod_perl` for this solution too?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/). It's Perl <--> web server without CGI.

> PSGI is an interface between Perl web applications and web servers,
>   and Plack is a Perl module and toolkit that contains PSGI middleware,
>   helpers and adapters to web servers.
>
> PSGI and Plack are inspired by Python's WSGI and Ruby's Rack.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If you are using Apache, the canonical way to do this is to use [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/products/apache-modules.html).

Note: mod_perl is more than just a Perl handler for Apache; it provides a standard interface (and many helper functions) for communicating with the webserver.